# Do I need to move my source code into my repo in github for windows

Tags: github

So I've just installed githib for windows. Do I actually need to move my source code into my repo now or do I leave it where it is and somehow point the repo to it?

eg if my app is at
c:\app
and the repo
at
c:\github\repo

do I need to copy everything into the repo?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The github instructions are pretty helpful.
Try: https://help.github.com/articles/create-a-repo

In Step 1 your app folder is equivalent to the folder the README file is in.

Comment: ah so I can creat me repo in the existing app location?

Comment: Yup! Basically you create a repo in you existing app location, then create a second repo on github, then copy (or *push*) your changes from your local repo to the github repo